# Connecting bluetooth headphones while app is recording in the background causes the recording to stop

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-audio, ios13, avaudioengine

I am facing the following issue and hoping someone else encountered it and can offer a solution:

1. I am using `AVAudioEngine` to access the microphone. Until iOS 12.4, every time the audio route changed I was able to restart the `AVAudioEngine` graph to reconfigure it and ensure the input/output audio formats fit the new input/output route. Due to changes introduced in iOS 12.4 it is no longer possible to start (or restart for that matter) an `AVAudioEngine` graph while the app is backgrounded (unless it's after an interruption).

The error Apple now throw when I attempt this is:

```
2019-10-03 18:34:25.702143+0200 [1703:129720] [aurioc] 1590: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561145187)
2019-10-03 18:34:25.702528+0200 [1703:129720] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561145187
2019-10-03 18:34:25.711668+0200 [1703:129720] [Error] Unable to start audio engine The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 561145187.)
```

I'm guessing Apple closed a security vulnerability there. So now I removed the code to restart the graph when an audio route is changed (e.g. bluetooth headphones are connected).

2. It seems like when an I/O audio format changes (as happens when the user connects a bluetooth device), an `.AVAudioEngingeConfigurationChange` notification is fired, to allow the integrating app to react to the change in format. This is really what I should've used to handle changes in I/O formats from the beginning, instead of brute forcing restarting the graph. According to the Apple documentation - “When the audio engine’s I/O unit observes a change to the audio input or output hardware’s channel count or sample rate, the audio engine stops, uninitializes itself, and issues this notification.” ([see the docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1389078-avaudioengineconfigurationchange)). When this happens while the app is backgrounded, I am unable to start the audio engine with the correct audio i/o formats, because of point #1.

So bottom line, it looks like by closing a security vulnerability, Apple introduced a bug in reacting to audio I/O format changes while the app is backgrounded. Or am I missing something?

I'm attaching a code snippet to better describe the issue. For a plug-and-play AppDelegate see here - https://gist.github.com/nevosegal/5669ae8fb6f3fba44505543e43b5d54b.

```
class RCAudioEngine {
​
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    init() {
        setup()
        start()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleConfigurationChange), name: .AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange, object: nil)
    }
​
    @objc func handleConfigurationChange() {
        //attempt to call start()
        //or to audioEngine.reset(), setup() and start()
        //or any other combination that involves starting the audioEngine
        //results in an error 561145187.
        //Not calling start() doesn't return this error, but also doesn't restart
        //the recording.
    }

    public func setup() {
​
        //Setup nodes
        let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
        let inputFormat = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
        let mainMixerNode = audioEngine.mainMixerNode
​
        //Mute output to avoid feedback
        mainMixerNode.outputVolume = 0.0
​
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 4096, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, _) -> Void in
            //Do audio conversion and use buffers
        }
    }
​
    public func start() {
        RCLog.debug("Starting audio engine")
        guard !audioEngine.isRunning else {
            RCLog.debug("Audio Engine is already running")
            return
        }
​
        do {
            audioEngine.prepare()
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            RCLog.error("Unable to start audio engine \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the (deprecated) AUGraph code equivalent work? Do you have some runnable code?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I haven't tried with AUGraph, but if I don't see a fix soon I'll definitely try spinning up an AudioUnit, it's just a bit of an overkill for my use case. Anyway, I'll add some more code to the snippet above to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I don't see what you're describing by just attaching BT headphones (AirPods). Is there something missing from your description or code? You might get similar behaviour if another audio app interrupts yours, but it's hard to tell what's going on or what should happen as there's no `AVAudioSession` configuration in your sample code.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I created a gist that contains the setup I'm using - https://gist.github.com/nevosegal/5669ae8fb6f3fba44505543e43b5d54b.

You can just copy and paste this AppDelegate to a new iOS project and you should be able to reproduce the issue easily. Note that the issue is not Bluetooth specific, it happens when the I/O format changed, so it would only work if you have an iPhone 6s and above (as those are running at 48kHz and bluetooth A2DP is 44.1kHZ). Otherwise simply change `.allowBluetoothA2DP` to `.allowBluetooth` and that should reproduce on every iOS device. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code on the weekend & can see that it doesn't work on 12.4 and does work on iOS 11. I can't add much except to say that over the years `AVAudioEngine` has disappointed me for all but the simplest use cases. Try recording with an remote-io `AudioUnit`.

Comment: Yep, that's very disappointing - I was trying to avoid that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I see only a fix that had gone into iOS 12.4. I am not sure if that causes the issue.

With the release notes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_12_4_release_notes

"Resolved an issue where running an app in iOS 12.2 or later under the Leaks instrument resulted in random numbers of false-positive leaks for every leak check after the first one in a given run. You might still encounter this issue in Simulator, or in macOS apps when using Instruments from Xcode 10.2 and later. (48549361)"

You can raise issue with Apple , if you are a signed developer. They might help you if the defect is on their part.

You can also test with upcoming iOS release to check if your code works in the future release (with the apple beta program)

Comment: Thanks. I already reported it to Apple, but I'm wondering if someone else encountered it and maybe found a workaround.